# If P=NP then how we can we say P=NP=NP-complete?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, np

[image]

In wikipedia I found this diagram. I don't get how under the asumption p=np we get p=np=np-complete?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cs.se] or [cstheory.se].

Comment: Why is it off topic? P- Np is a very necessary idea that a programmer should have.

Comment: [so] is typically more appropriate for questions regarding actual code. Questions about Computer Science theory are better suited on one of the above-mentioned sites. This is more a case of "This would be much better suited there" as "This absolutely doesn't belong here".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure this is on topic for stack overflow (Theoretical Comp Sci), but NP-hard, as correctly visualized in the diagram is "the set of problems that are at least as hard as those in NP"; this includes problems that are *worse* than NP in one sense or another.

NP-complete problems are those problems in NP-hard that have a reducibility relationship with specific problems that are known to be in NP. Essentially, every problem that can be converted in polynomial time or better to a problem in NP-complete is just as hard as the others.

Here are a couple good snippets from [CLRS](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) that illustrate the issue:

> The class NP consists of those problems that are “verifiable” in polynomial time. What do we mean by a problem being verifiable? If we were somehow given a "certificate” of a solution, then we could verify that the certificate is correct in time polynomial in the size of the input to the problem.

---

> Informally, a problem is in the class NPC—and we refer to it as being NP-complete—if it is in NP and is as “hard” as any problem in NP.

---

> A decidable language L is NP-complete if:
>
> 1. L is in NP, and
> 2. L' can be reduced to L in polynomial time for every L' in NP.
>
> If a language L satisfies property 2, but not necessarily property 1, we say that L is NP-hard. We also define NPC to be the class of NP-complete languages.

(I may have the L' and L backwards there, the reducibility symbol is backwards from the way it is read in English.)

So what's the point? Well, you can just solve it with set theory: NP-complete is a subset of NP, and if P=NP, then NP-complete is a subset of P (in fact, they all become equal at that point, since you can solve any of them by first changing them to something your magic P-algorithm can work on). NP-hard still includes some NP-complete problems, but there are other problems outside, which are just **hard**.

Comment: Ok, I got it. So if p=np then every problem in np can be solved in polynomial time and thus every problem in npc can also be solved in polynomial time. So p=np=npc.

Comment: "Every problem in NPC can also be solved in polynomial time". This only implies that NPC is a subset of P. Not that its equal.